# Nested documents in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm writing an asset management application. It lets users store arbitrary asset attributes by adding an html control such as a text field, select menu, etc. to the asset. A JSON representation of the attribute then becomes part of the asset JSON document stored in couchdb. An asset has the following structure in couchdb:

```
{
   "_id": "9399fb27448b1e5dfdca0181620418d4",
   "_rev": "12-fa50eae8b50f745f9852e9fab30ef5d9",
   "type": "asset",
   "attributes": [
       {
           "id": "9399fb27448b1e5dfdca01816203d609",
           "type": "text",
           "heading": "Brand",
           "data": "",
           "requiredBySystem": true
       },
       {
           "id": "9399fb27448b1e5dfdca01816203e68e",
           "type": "userSelectMenu",
           "heading": "Assigned To",
           "data": "",
           "requiredBySystem": true
       },
       {
           "id": "9399fb27448b1e5dfdca01816203e9c9",
           "type": "categories",
           "heading": "Categories",
           "data": [
               "0d7e6233e5f48b4f55c5376bf00b1be5",
               "0d7e6233e5f48b4f55c5376bf00d94cf"
           ],
           "requiredBySystem": true
       },
       {
           "id": "9399fb27448b1e5dfdca01816207uy5a",
           "type": "radio",
           "heading": "Radio Buttons",
           "data": [
               {
                   "text": "Button 1",
                   "checked": false
               },
               {
                   "text": "Button 2",
                   "checked": true
               }
           ],
           "requiredBySystem": true
       },
       {
           "id": "9399fb27448b1e5dfdca01816205tgh6",
           "type": "checkboxes",
           "heading": "Checkboxes",
           "data": [
             {
                 "text": "Box 1",
                 "checked": false
             },
             {
                 "text": "Box 2",
                 "checked": true
             }
           ],
           "requiredBySystem": true
       },
       {
           "id": "9399fb27448b1e5dfdca0181620k81gt",
           "type": "select",
           "heading": "Select Menu",
           "data": [
               {
                   "text": "Option 1",
                   "checked": false
               },
               {
                   "text": "Option 2",
                   "checked": true
               }
           ],
           "requiredBySystem": true
       }
   ]
}
```

I'm not sure if putting attributes in an array is the best way to allow searching for an asset based on an attribute value. Would it be better to attach the attribute directly to the asset as a property? I'm experimenting now in elasticsearch. If I try and store the document as is, elasticsearch returns an error:

"error" : "MapperParsingException[Failed to parse [attributes.data]]; nested: ElasticSearchIllegalArgumentException[unknown property [text]]; "

I"m using the following mapping:

```
"mappings" : {
    "asset" : {
      "properties" : {
        "_id": {
          "type" : "string",
          "index" : "not_analyzed"
        },
        "_rev": {
          "type" : "string",
          "index" : "not_analyzed"
        },
        "type": {
          "type" : "string",
          "index" : "not_analyzed"
        },
        "attributes": {
          "properties" : {
            "id" : {
              "type" : "string"
            },
            "type" : {
              "type" : "string",
              "index" : "not_analyzed"
            },
            "heading" : {
              "type" : "string"
            },
            "data" : {
              "type" : "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Not sure where I'm going wrong here. Thanks for your help!

Troy

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem is arising from the way your document is structured.  `attribute.data` is both a string/array of strings and a full, inner object.  ES doesn't allow the "type" of a property to change.

Basically, you can't have this:

`"data": [
  "0d7e6233e5f48b4f55c5376bf00b1be5",
  "0d7e6233e5f48b4f55c5376bf00d94cf"
],`

and this:

```
"data":[
  {
    "text":"Button 1",
    "checked":false
  },
  {
    "text":"Button 2",
    "checked":true
  }
],
```

in the same document.  The first instance of `data` tells ES that "data is an array of strings". But then the second instance of `data` says "Hey, I'm an object!", which is why ES is throwing an error.

You can sidestep this issue by explicitly declaring `data` as an object and setting **enabled: false**, but this is probably not the solution you want (since that just tells ES to store `data` as a text field, with no parsing.

The other option is to either restructure your data, or split `data` into it's document (e.g. Parent/Child mapping)

Comment: If I split it into its own document using a parent/child mapping, can data then be different types? In the database it can be a string, an array of objects or an array of strings. Would it be better to use different properties based on the data type e.g. a string could just be a 'text' property, an array of objects could be a 'choices' property, etc.

Comment: I may have misspoke...I'm not sure Parent/Child types will allow mixed data types on the same field either.  If you can, splitting your data into separate fields would be the easiest way to do it.  Adds a bit more complexity on your end since you have to juggle more properties though.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm going to go with that approach. Thank you!